# Как проверить массив на соответствие по символам?

Tags: javascript, массивы

К примеру есть массив

```
var arr = [ 'xyz', 'xzy', 'yxz', 'ex', 'yzx', 'zxy', 'zyx', 'zyxy' ]
```

Как можно проверить все его элементы так, чтобы отсекались только те, в которых есть только 3 символа 'x', 'y' и  'z' в любом порядке? То есть чтобы вывелся только элементы 'ex', 'zyxy'

Comment: Нет, только если в элементе 3 символа 'x', 'y' и 'z'. То есть к примеру 'xyzy' надо вывести

Comment: Тогда об этом стоит уточнить в вопросе. Как-то так: _"отсекались только те, в которых есть только символы 'x', 'y' и 'z' (по одному каждого) в любом порядке"_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, похоже что придется идти некрасивым путем:

```js
var arr = [ 'xyz', 'xyzy', 'xzy', 'yxz', 'ex', 'yzx', 'zxy', 'zyx', 'xz' ]


var result = arr.filter(el => el.length !== 3
                           || el.indexOf('x') < 0
                           || el.indexOf('y') < 0
                           || el.indexOf('z') < 0);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @Regent благодарю за сообщение

Comment: AGS17, спасибо большое